# Visibility Detector flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, visibilitychange

I am using visibility detector in flutter to check for 100% visibility of a widget. But even when the widget is behind a fixed app bar the visibility detector considers it to be 100% visible. What is the solution for considering it to be visible only when its below navigation bar?

Comment: can you provide more context?

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem

Comment: @SuzZan The visibility detector considering visibility to be 100% even when the portion of it is hidden below a fixed app bar. But want I solution that visibility is considered only for portion that is outside nav bar i.e., less than 100%.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet?